# Java code for String arrays populating a ComboBox

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

```
years = new String[67];
for(int y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13; y <= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 80; y++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < years.length; i++){
        years[i] = Integer.toString(y);
    }
}
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(years));
```

I have this code for populating ComboBox with 67 dates however all I'm getting is empty values?

Answer (score 4):

The body of the outer loop will never execute since the loop condition is false on the first iteration:

You try to go from `x - 13` *up* to `x - 80`.

```
for(int y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13; y <= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 80; y++)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               this is higher than...    ...this even in the first iteration
```

Also, to make sure `-13` to `-80` actually adds up to the length of the `years` array, I'd suggest you write it like this:

```
String[] years = new String[67];
int thisYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int startYear = thisYear - 13;

for (int i = 0; i < years.length; i++)
    years[i] = Integer.toString(startYear - i);

jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(years));
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the calendar is initialized with the current time, you go from year 1999 to year 1932. That makes an empty loop.

And what's the point in having those two nested loops?

Answer (score 0):

```
years = new String[67];
int index = 0;

    for(int y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13; y >= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 80; y--) {

            years[index++] = Integer.toString(y);
    }

jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(years));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13; y >= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 80; **y--**) {
```

Comment: You need to compare using `>=` as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop end condition is true at the first iteration. Use this instead:

```
years = new String[67];

         for(int i = 0; i < years.length; i++){

            years[i] = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13-i);
         }

jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(years));
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues jump out at me:
One, your loop executes exactly 0 times since `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13` <= `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 80` so the loop will exit immediately.

Two, since you are going from a larger value (`cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 13`) to a smaller one (`cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 80`), you should not do `y++` since it will increase y, you should instead use `y--`.

Finally, `for(int i = 0; i < years.length; i++)` will replace ALL of the values in years.